# PL/SQL: Function Created with compilation Error

Tags: sql, function, plsql

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting compilation error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_balance_due
(order_id_f NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
AS 
balance_due_f NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(total_amount) INTO balance_due_f 
FROM order_lines, orders
WHERE order_id_f = order_line.order_id;
RETURN balance_due_f;
End;
```

Errors are

```
LINE/COL  ERROR  
7/1  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
9/20  PL/SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

I tried to do a regular select query and it worked

```
SELECT SUM(total_amount)
FROM order_lines, orders
WHERE order_lines.order_id = orders.order_id and orders.order_id = 12
```

The function should do SUM of amount for the desired order_id and return it...

The error message is: **Function created with compilation errors**

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Thank you, still same error message

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of `balance_due_f NUMBER`.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thank you, new errors appeared

Comment: You're working with tables `order_lines` and `orders`, but in the WHERE clause you try to compare to `order_line.order_id`. So is the table named `order_lines` or `order_line`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you get this error try to fully qualify the columns you use.

Instead of `order_id_f = order_line.order_id` try `TABLENAME.order_id_f = order_line.order_id`.

See: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00918_column_ambiguously_defined.htm